# iOS prevent given requests on Cellular Data

Tags: ios, 3g

I am planning my application to perform some requests to remote server on 3G and WiFi, and other requests only on WiFi.

How do I enable/disable requests over 3G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Reachability` classes to get informations about the current connection / connectivity. Search for `Reachability 3.0`.

Comment: Is it a code sample provided from Apple? If so, thanks I'll go have a look at it. I didn't know where to start looking.

Comment: You get the Apple provided source here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Introduction/Intro.html